# MDT-2010 Some Packages start without others finishing

Tags: deployment, mdt-2010, autocad

I am trying to deploy Autodesk suite through MDT. I have my packages. They are packaged as exe files with some switches.

The Problem is when I try to deploy them Autocad starts to install and revit trys to go before it has finished then Inventor does the same thing.

On my final status page of MDT i have three errors which are the Autodesk packages. 
The first package ends up installing correctly however MDT detects that it failed because it is still running when the deployment ends.

The other 2 packages (revit and inventor) show up with the msi error that another application is running (this is expected because there IS another application running) So why doesnt MDT see that?

Is there something I can do to recitfy this?
Perhaps have a script that runs and tells the apps to wait if setup is running or something?

Or is it possible to pause MDT till the app installs.
Any Ideas would be great.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a problem with the exe installer in that the primary exe you are running isn't the main installer process, it just kicks off the real installer and exits.  So the task sequence thinks the step is finished and it can move on to the next step.

I could've sworn Autodesk apps have a deployment tool that can create a standard MSI deployment.  If you change your task sequence steps to use msiexec with the MSI, you probably won't have the problem anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this before where McAfee had chained install packages inside the top package I specified in MDT. If the original package exits with error code 0/3010, it is marked as successful and MDT will continue.

Try breaking them out, or like Ryan mentioned look into a deployment tool by Autodesk.